# Apex - Example Of Creating Case Record When Field On Account Equals "xxx"?

Tags: apex, trigger, account, person-accounts, case-object

Continuing my quest to get Apex and Triggers under my belt:   Can someone offer either sample code or links to samples where (such as) when Account.ABCD now equals "Go", create a Case Record and write some values to a few fields?

It would be greatly appreciated.  We simply want to create a Case of Type "A" when one thing happens on the Account, "B" for another, etc...

Comment: What is the triggering behavior which causes the Case to be created? (Insert / Update of Account?)

Comment: Account.ABCD equals "A", then we'd create a Case with certain info... Account.ABCD equals "B", similar scenario, to be clear.   It would not be just first occurrence (which would be more complicated I assume anyway), it would be anytime it changes to "A" or "B".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First off, this is the [approved Salesforce "Hello World" class and trigger](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_qs_HelloWorld.htm). Also, take some time to understand [Triggers](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers.htm) and [Trigger Context Variables](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm). You **absolutely must know** the different context variables that are available and when. You also need fully understand that triggers **execute in batch**. Never, expect a trigger to only work on a single update. If you run a process that updates 5 accounts, your trigger will only run **ONCE**. This is crucial to understand.

Secondly, I'll show you some code. As someone who has worked on some very complex applications on the Force.com platform, I always use a separate class for all of my functionality. I only like creating one trigger per object and then I use the context variables to then call separate methods on a helper class. With that said, here is the code sample (that I wrote specifically on this site and have no idea if it actually compiles/runs, it is purely a sample - Also, I normally do not code with comments like this, but it is for educational purposes. Clean code doesn't normally have many comments in my opinion):

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (after insert, after update) {
    // Create an instance of your helper class
    AccountTriggerHelper helper = new AccountTriggerHelper();

    // Even though this trigger only works after insert or after update currently,
    // there is nothing to stop you from adding to it in the future. Adding this
    // logic will allow you to expand in the future.
    //
    // This says run if the trigger is after the insert OR after the update
    if((Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert) || (Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate)){
        // Now call your helper method
        helper.createCaseWhenNeeded(Trigger.new);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class AccountTriggerHelper{
   public void createCaseWhenNeeded(List<Account> accounts){
       // We need to store a List of Cases to create.
       List<Case> casesToCreate = new List<Case>();

       // Loop over the accounts. Remember, we don't know how many accounts we will have
       for(Account acc:accounts){
           // This is where you need to determine what your condition will be.
           // You will replicate this system with more if statements or else if
           // statements
           if(acc.Name == 'CreateCase'){
               // Your account meets the criteria, create the case you want and
               // add it to your List of cases
               Case caseToAdd = new Case();

               // Set up any fields you want
               caseToAdd.Name = 'Test';
               caseToAdd.Custom_Field__c = 'Something';
               casesToCreate.add(caseToAdd);

               // You could have also used the following...
               // new Case(Name = 'Test',Custom_Field__c = 'Something');
               // All you need to do is comma delimit all of the fields you want to add
               // Depending on how many fields you want to add, it can be cleaner to 
               // create it like above and then just add it all in one statement
           }
       }

       // You have your full List of cases to add, now just run the insert DML statement
       insert cases;
   }
}
```

You now need to create your [unit tests](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests). Remember, Apex code requires 75% code coverage and all triggers require at least 1% code coverage to be deployed to a production system. To round it all out, here are some references to the things I did in the code:

- [Apex Classes](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_classes_understanding.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fapex_classes_understanding.htm|SkinName=webhelp)
- [Lists](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_collections_lists.htm) and [List Methods](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_collections_lists.htm)
- [Loops](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_loops.htm), specifically a [List or Set `for` Loop](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_loops_for_lists.htm)
- [Comparison](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_understanding.htm), specifically in an [if statement](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_if_else.htm)
- [DML](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dml.htm) and the [use of `insert`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dml_insert.htm)

Comment: Thanks for this excellent example... if you do not mind:   At the casesToCreate.add, how would I refer to the same added case to set 2-4 more fields ON that new case before committing with the insert below?  THANKS AGAIN.

Comment: I edited my example to add what you needed.

Comment: Absolutely perfect.  I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Yep. No problem. Enjoy!

Comment: I may need to make this a new question.... but:   What do I do about it firing EVERY TIME the record is edited after the criteria is true?  The idea is to create a case when (in your code) acc.Name is TRUE the FIRST time, not EVERY time.  My logic only tells me to make a hidden field to tick off when I fire it, then unset that field if the acc.Name ever changes.... any better ideas?

Comment: That is all apart of Trigger context variables. You will need to use Trigger.old and then compare the old value with the new value. Only perform the Case creation when the new value meets the requirements and the old value was different

Comment: I got it... ALMOST (dammit).  http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9752/apex-checking-trigger-old-versus-trigger-new  Has my issues spelled out, it's something stupid simple again I think.

Comment: Kind of like this..  Account old = Trigger.oldMap.get(a.Id);if (a.Accountfield__c != old.Accountfield__c) {