# Apex - Checking Trigger.OLD versus Trigger.NEW

Tags: apex, trigger, class, case-object

(thanks to @JesseAltman for help with the initial code)

I am trying to make sure this fires once each time the IF comes true (checking if the field was previously something different).  I am doing something wrong at either the Map line or the line directly above.  Error =

```
Illegal assignment from LIST<SObject> to SOBJECT:Account at line 14 column 12
```

...which points to the line ABOVE Map.  I pulled these two lines from another site, but they were corrupted (Map.get was right next to trigger.old with no space between).  Help??   :-(

```
public class AccountTriggerHelper{

   public void createCaseWhenNeeded(List<Account> accounts){

       // We need to store a List of Cases to create.
       List<Case> casesToCreate = new List<Case>();

       // Loop over the accounts. Remember, we don't know how many accounts we will have
       for(Account acc:accounts){

           // This is where you need to determine what your condition will be.
           // You will replicate this system with more if statements or else if
           // statements
LINE 14:   Account beforeUpdate = System.Trigger.old;
           Map.get(acc.Id);
           if( beforeUpdate.LastName != 'CreateCase' && acc.LastName = 'CreateCase' ) {

       // Your account meets the criteria, create the case you want and
       // add it to your List of cases
               Case caseToAdd = new Case();
       // Set up any fields you want
               caseToAdd.AccountId = acc.Id;
               caseToAdd.RecordTypeId = '012600000005DYN';
               caseToAdd.Origin = 'Receptionist';
               caseToAdd.Products__c = 'Other';
               casesToCreate.add(caseToAdd);

           }

       // You have your full List of cases to add, now just run the insert DML statement
       insert casesToCreate;
       }
   }
}
```

UPDATE:

Error if I use THIS instead of the line 14-15 above -

```
Illegal assignment from SObject to SOBJECT:Account at line 14 column 12
```

(when using...)

```
Account beforeUpdate = System.Trigger.oldMap.get(acc.Id);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the code you pulled wasn't corrupted - it was using `Trigger.oldMap` (a Map of Ids -> SObjects) instead of `Trigger.old` (a list of SObjects).

Try combining lines 14 and 15 to make:

```
Account beforeUpdate = System.Trigger.oldMap.get(acc.Id);
```

**Update**: Are you even sure that the Trigger context variables are valid when this method is called, since you're not passing them in with the method call? To use `Trigger.oldMap` this code would need to be in the trigger - when it is, the trigger understands that `Trigger.old` is a list of whatever object the trigger is on (in this case, the Account object). Outside of a trigger's context, though, the Apex parser would give you the error you're seeing.

Try passing in the oldMap in with the method call:

```
public class AccountTriggerHelper {
   public static void createCaseWhenNeeded(List<Account> accounts, Map<Id, Account> oldMap){
        List<Case> casesToCreate = new List<Case>();
        for(Account acc:accounts){
            Account beforeUpdate = oldMap.get(acc.Id);
            if( beforeUpdate.LastName != 'CreateCase' && acc.LastName == 'CreateCase' ) {
                Case caseToAdd = new Case();
                caseToAdd.AccountId = acc.Id;
                caseToAdd.RecordTypeId = '012600000005DYN';
                caseToAdd.Origin = 'Receptionist';
                caseToAdd.Products__c = 'Other';
                casesToCreate.add(caseToAdd);
            }
        }
        insert casesToCreate;
   }
}
```

This would allow you to just call the following in your Account trigger:

```
AccountTriggerHelper.createCaseWhenNeeded(Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap);
```

Comment: Tried that... UPDATE added to original post at bottom.

Comment: @AMM I have updated my answer. The code you found was most likely intended for use within the trigger itself, so you'll need to pass `Trigger.oldMap` in with the method call to your helper class in order to reference it.

Comment: The updated PUBLIC statement did not work; same exact error.  :-/  Sorry.

Comment: Illegal assignment from SObject to SOBJECT:Account at line 15 column 12

Comment: Odd.  I pasted your WHOLE code just in case you changed something I'm not noticing, and I'm getting a dumb error saying I can't use Ampersand in the IF because it's not boolean).  Digging.......     DO I NEED to do something for the oldmap in the TRIGGER that calls the function?

Comment: @AMM the second term in the if statement should be `acc.LastName == 'CreateCase'`, I'll update the answer with an extra "=".

Comment: With YOUR code, it's the IF statement that fails, bizarrely enough:    AND operator can only be applied to Boolean expressions at line 11 column 57    .... I'm not seeing any reason for that.

Comment: @AMM please see my last comment, the code you posted was assigning a value to `acc.LastName` rather than checking for equality, and I missed it when posting my response. Just change the single `=` to `==` in the term after `&&` and you should be fine.

Comment: Ug.  Makes sense now.... regarding the trigger now:  How does this new PUBLIC affect the call to the Function?  It's failing now, I am not sure what second item to put into the function call (apparently it's not simply Trigger.old).  Currently it is this, and I apparently need a second parameter:       
        helper.createCaseWhenNeeded(Trigger.new);

Comment: I'm going to take this to a new question - this is getting convoluted....  thanks for the help!