# Triggers for parsing Subject and auto fill the fields in the case

Tags: apex, trigger

I am new to Apex coding and trying to write some triggers with the help of online community :-)
The current issue that i am trying to work is `to parse the subject of the case and if that contains a customer name that is exactly equal to the Account name, then auto populate the account name.`

For example, subject of the case has `[abc corp] Please open a case for this issue`, then the account name to auto fill with `abc corp`. The account object has `abc corp`

can anybody help with a sample code that help me to address this issue?

Regards
Deepak

Comment: You should not ask community to write code for you. Here are some exapmles. Hope they help you. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9708/apex-example-of-creating-case-record-when-field-on-account-equals-xxx  https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F000000092PHIAY

Comment: Are you saying that the Account name is always delimited so you can extract it (and only it) from any Case subject line?

Comment: Yes Keith. Account Name is always delimited in the subject and hence i want to extract it and fill it in account name.

Comment: Atul, thanks for the links and references. i will go through them. since i am new to these, i am asking the community to help with samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer the below code

```
trigger beforeInsertCase on Case (before insert) {

    List<String> subjectList = new List<String>();
    Map<String,Id> accNameIdMap = new Map<String,Id>();

    for(Case c:trigger.new){
        Integer startIndex = c.subject.indexOf('[')+1;
        Integer endIndex = c.subject.indexOf(']');
        subjectList.add(c.subject.substring(startIndex,endIndex));
    }

    for(Account acct:[Select id,name From Account Where name In:subjectList]){
        accNameIdMap.put(acct.name,acct.id);
    }

    if(null != accNameIdMap && !accNameIdMap.isEmpty()){
        for(Case c:trigger.new){
            for(String accName:accNameIdMap.keySet()){
                if(c.subject.contains(accName)){
                    c.accountId = accNameIdMap.get(accName);
                }
            }
        }
    }          
}
```

Here I have assumed that account name is enclosed within square brackets in the subject.

Comment: Thank you Codebadit. It perfectly worked for me. But it was giving error "Ending position out of bound: -1". So i added a condition before searching for '['. So my final code looks like this. This is perfectly working for me now for all permutations and combinations

Comment: Glad I was some help to you!

Answer (score 1):

```
trigger UpdateFromEmail on Case (before insert) {

    List<String> subjectList = new List<String>();
    Map<String,Id> accNameIdMap = new Map<String,Id>();
    String string1 = '[';
    String string2 = ']';

    for(Case c:trigger.new){
        if (c.subject.contains(string1) && c.subject.contains(string2))
        {
        Integer startIndex = c.subject.indexOf('[')+1;
        Integer endIndex = c.subject.indexOf(']');
        subjectList.add(c.subject.substring(startIndex,endIndex));
       }

    }

    for(Account acct:[Select id,name From Account Where name In:subjectList]){
        accNameIdMap.put(acct.name,acct.id);
    }

    if(null != accNameIdMap && !accNameIdMap.isEmpty()){
        for(Case c:trigger.new){
            for(String accName:accNameIdMap.keySet()){
                if(c.subject.contains(accName)){
                    c.accountId = accNameIdMap.get(accName);
                }
            }
        }
    }          
}
```